How to use TimeSeriesSplit for panel data?
I have been trying to use TimeSeriesSplit for panel data. By panel data I mean yearly pictures of the population. I was interested in splitting the data along the years. That population is evolving and each year do not contain the same population size. Hence the direct use of the TimeSeriesSplit is not possible.
Basically I was trying to get the following CV scheme:

I manage to do this withe following code:
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.dummy import DummyRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit

X_test, y_test = [], []

start_year = 2010
end_year = 2020

for year in np.arange(start_year, end_year+1):
    X_year, y_year = make_regression(n_samples=5+year-start_year, n_features=2, bias=100, noise=1, random_state=year)
    X_year = pd.DataFrame(X_year).rename(columns={0:'X1', 1:'X2'})
    X_year['year'] = year
    y_year = pd.Series(y_year)
    X_test.append(X_year)
    y_test.append(y_year)
    
X_test, y_test = pd.concat(X_test), pd.concat(y_test)

# modelling

X = X_test
y = y_test
years = np.unique(X_test['year'])

# modelisation
model = DummyRegressor(strategy="mean")
metric = mean_squared_error
cv = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=len(years)-1)

years_folds = []
res = []

for i, (train_year, test_year) in enumerate(cv.split(years)):
    
    print(f"Fold {i}:")
    print(f"  Train: index={years[train_year]}")
    print(f"  Test:  index={years[test_year]}")
    
    years_folds.append((years[train_year], years[test_year]))
    
    train_filter = X['year'].isin(years[train_year])
    test_filter = X['year'].isin(years[test_year])
    
    X_train, y_train = X.loc[train_filter.values], y[train_filter.values]
    X_test, y_test = X.loc[test_filter.values], y[test_filter.values]
    
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    score = metric(model.predict(X_test), y_test)
    print(f' {score=:.3}')
    res.append((years[test_year][0], score))

plot_year_folds(years_folds)
    
folds_res = pd.DataFrame(res,columns=['test_year', metric.__name__])
folds_res.plot.scatter(x='test_year', y=metric.__name__, title=f'{metric.__name__} over test_year');

Note: I use a dummy dataset and a dummy model for the sake of providing a running example. It is not the main topic of my post.
As you can notice I have to use a trick: I split the years and not the data. I am wondering: is there a standard way to split the data with a sklearn cv object ? The goal is to use it in a cross_val_score function.

HI Lucas, is it something that would fit your need
Otherwise the sklearn cross_val_score can be given the array of indices of your split. In that case you can generates your indices first and throw it in the cross_val_score. Happy to discuss in more detail in dm/discord if I misunderstood the objective

Yes it does. I have managed to use the code as intended, in a sklearn cross_val_score call.  Should I put the code as an answer ?

As mentionned, mlxtend allows to do so.
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import seaborn as sns, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.dummy import DummyRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, make_scorer
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

from mlxtend.evaluate.time_series import GroupTimeSeriesSplit, plot_splits

X_test, y_test = [], []

start_year = 2010
end_year = 2020

for year in np.arange(start_year, end_year+1):
    X_year, y_year = make_regression(n_samples=5+(year-start_year), n_features=2, bias=0, noise=1, random_state=year)
    X_year = pd.DataFrame(X_year).rename(columns={0:'X1', 1:'X2'})
    X_year['year'] = year
    y_year = pd.Series(y_year)
    X_test.append(X_year)
    y_test.append(y_year)

X, y = pd.concat(X_test), pd.concat(y_test)

# modelisation
model = DummyRegressor(strategy="mean")
metric = mean_squared_error
cv_args = {"test_size": 1, 'n_splits': len(np.unique(X['year'])) - 1, 'window_type': 'expanding'}
cv = GroupTimeSeriesSplit(**cv_args)

scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=cv, groups=X['year'], scoring=make_scorer(metric))

plot_splits(X, y, X['year'], **cv_args)


It allows to use sklearn cross_val_score. It still has some drawbacks (adding a dependency, the plot can be improved), but it answers my needs.
Note: I have raised both of the following issues.

git issue with sklearn to improve ts split
git issue with mlxtend to improve the plot

